# overlapping Navbar in bootstrap in a Django template

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar is overlapping my web, and I don't know how to change it.
Now is :
[image]

You can see the number of events and the blue button for create a new event, are cut in the middle by navbar.

My templates are:

navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'events_app:panel' %}">Eventus</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><p class="navbar-text">Bienvenido,  <a href="#" class="navbar-link">{{ user.username|capfirst }}</a></p></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'users_app:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

panel.html

```
{% block title %}Panel{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

{% include "events/panel/navbar.html" %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header ">
            <h4>
                <strong>
                    Tienes <span class="label label-warning">0</span> Eventos disponibles
                </strong>
                <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="{% url 'events_app:nuevo' %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Crear un evento nuevo
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div><!-- page-header -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Nombre del evento</th>
                    <th>Categoría</th>
                    <th>Inicio</th>
                    <th>Fin</th>
                    <th>Monto</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="" alt="" width="60" class="img-rounded">
                        </td>
                        <td>name</td>
                        <td>category</td>
                        <td>start</td>
                        <td>finish</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="label label-default">Gratuito</span>
                            <span class="label label-info">S/. 0.00</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

{% endblock content %}
```

I try to change class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" but it don't change my view of the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Bootstrap docs:

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>   Copy
>
> `body { padding-top: 70px; }`
>
> Make sure to include this **after** the core Bootstrap CSS.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: I try this but it is the same

Comment: Did adding the css `body {padding-top: 70px;}` have no effect?

Comment: Yes I put it and don't change it.

Comment: Try doing afterwards a hard refresh of your browser, e.g ctrl + F5 in chrome